# No Cocoapods - Need to add performance monitoring for iOS manually

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-performance

I need to integrate Firebase performance monitoring for my app. I can't use cocoa pods in this project. I must need to download a framework because it has its own cocoapod `Firebase/performance` .

The documentation only includes the pod file to add. Not a manual option.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-ios

Please help where can I find/ how can I add the `Firebase/performance` library/dependency to my project.

I already have `Firebase` , I need `Firebase/performance`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase documentation gives instructions for this in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks):

> If you don't want to use Cocoapods, you can still take advantage of
>   the Firebase SDKs by importing the frameworks directly.
>
> 1. Download the framework SDK zip. This is a ~1GB file and might take some time to download.
> 2. Unzip the file, then review the README for the Frameworks that you want to include in your app.
> 3. Add the ObjC linker flag in your Other Linker Settings in your target's build settings.

Follow the link to the documentation to find the actual link to download the frameworks zip.